# How do I solve this limit scenario?

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is continuous at $5$ and $f(5)=2$ and $f(4)=3$, then $\lim_{x \to 2} f(4x^2-11)=2$

Is the above statement true or false with an explanation for the answer?

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: The composition of continuous functions is continuous. So $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x))=f(\lim_{u\to g(a)}u)=f(g(a))$ when $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$. Apply this with $g(x)=4x^2-11$.

Comment: The fact that $f(4)=3$ is totally irrelevant and is just meant to confuse and distract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Theorem: if $g$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(x_0)$, then the composite function $f(g(x))=fog(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$.

As you noted $f$ is continuous at $5$ and you know that polynomials are continuous at every real numbers especially at $x_0=2$. so $$\lim_{x\to2}f(4x^2-11)=f(\lim_{x\to2}(4x^2-11))=f(4*2^2-11)=f(5)=2$$

Comment: Sorry. I'm not trying to copy you. I was typing (while trying to talk on the phone) as you were answering, I guess.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: It is Ok. :) Anyway, anon gave him the final answer at above comment **first**.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous at $5$, and $5$ is the limit of $4x^2-11$ as $x$ approaches $2$, you make take the limit "inside the function" to see that the value of the limit is $f(5)=2$.